# Installing a transparent window in waterproof tool boxes

Tags: tools, waterproofing, storage, plastic

I have a bunch of waterproof toolkit boxes that I usually keep in the shed, which are IP67 rated. I'm horribly unorganised and frequently switch tools between them, so I can never quickly work out if the one I'm opening is likely to have the tool I'm looking for. I also frequently forget to put them away, and they sit out in the rain for a day or so. Any kind of sorting and tidying regimen, as I have previously demonstrated to myself, is doomed to fail.

As such, I'd like to fit a small transparent window in the top of each. The boxes are plastic (ABS?) so I could easily take a drill to them and install some acrylic glass, but I'd rather do a decent job of it.

I'm not hugely concerned about retaining the IP67 rating, as something roughly around the IP65 level will do just fine, but I do want to make sure that moisture can't seep in and ruin all my tools.

Any suggestions on how to make a clean rectangular cut in the top of the boxes, and how to seal the "windows" in place without making a total mess and leaking water everywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Make a clean *round* hole with a hole-saw and put in a larger polycarbonate (e.g. Lexan) window, with caulking on the surface, and perhaps three bolts, also caulked, to keep it in place.

Acrylic will quickly get scratched or crazed, or just break.